# Unexpected Token node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an application which requires notification and I have made a research that firebase function is very useful for doing this type of feature. As a result, I have watched some youtube and forum tutorial in order to integrate this feature but now I am facing issue that during the deployment process. So, when I deployed this flowing code to the firebase function I got an unexpected token " "I couldn't even know where is the error in my code

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{PostKey}/{notification_id}').onWrite((date,context) =>{

 const user_id = context.params.PostKey;
 const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


 console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id,'this also notification_id',notification_id);

 const Device_token = admin.database().ref(`/User_Data/${user_id}/Device_token`).once('value');
 return Device_token = admin.then(response =>
 {
     const token_id = result.val();
     const payload = 
     {
         notification:
         {
             title:"Appointment",
             body" "Appointment has been booked",
             icon:"default"
         };
     };
     return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload)
                              .then(response => {
                                  return console.log('This was the notification feature');


                             });
 });













});
```

Comment: Check the definition of `payload`, it contains a couple of issues.

Comment: Notice also, that you're trying to re-assign a value to the constant `Device_token`.

Comment: i have assigned Device_Token and then i return to it

Comment: "return to it" There no such a feature in JS, retun ends the execution of the function, and returns a value to its caller.

Comment: Hi @Teemu I am new to node js, this the first code i  developed in js, the problem when I delete it  I got "Expected catch() or return  promise /catch-or-return and when I leave it as it is, it worked and I deployed to firebase function but now i am getting an error in firebase function log :admin.database.ref is not a function

Comment: I've rolled back the edits, because they invalidate the posted answer to the original question. Don't fix the question according to the answers or comments. If fixing your real code results in new errors, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 syntax errors in the code you sent:

- Line 23: There's a double quote instead of a colon to separate the object key from the value
- Line 25: You use a semi-colon instead of a comma to separate object entries
- Line 34: You forgot to close the block started at line 6 with the anonymous function passed as parameter to the `onWrite` function.

I would recommend you to use a JavaScript IDE when writing this kind of code. Such as Visual Studio Code which is free and open source.

Comment: I have edit it right now, can you please checked again . Thanks in advance

Comment: I still see the second issue at line 25, can you fix it and try again?

Comment: I have updated and now I am getting an error in the firebase function log,, TypeError: admin.database.ref is not a function
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:19:37)